# My computer turns on, then turns off immediately, without booting

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply

Hardware I am using:

Intel Core i7-7700K 4.2 GHz Quad-Core Processor

Noctua NH-D15 82.5 CFM CPU Cooler

Asus PRIME Z390-A Motherboard

2x Corsair Vengeance LPX 8 GB DDR4-3000 Memory

Samsung 860 Evo 1 TB 2.5" Solid State Drive

MSI GeForce RTX 2070 8 GB Video Card

NZXT H510 ATX Mid Tower Case

EVGA 850 W 80+ Gold Certified Semi-modular ATX Power Supply

When I push the power button, the LED light around it turns on, the fans on the CPU cooler and the case spin, then the LED on the right of the motherboard next to CPU flashes, then the whole thing turns off and the fans stop spinning.

I switched the RAM to other slots, I switched out the CPU's power cable, and everything was working before I just switched out the motherboard for the current one (the Asus PRIME Z390-A). I checked the CPU and none of the pins looked bent.

What am I missing?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106502/discussion-on-question-by-max-my-computer-turns-on-then-turns-off-immediately).

Answer (score 1):

The CPU I was using isn't compatible according to https://www.asus.com/fr/Motherboards/PRIME-Z390-A/HelpDesk_CPU/